# Where is an .o file stored when using setup.py install?

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, setuptools

Generally, where is the x.o file stored when x.cpp and x.h are compiled?

Specifically, how to fix the error

```
megatron/fused_kernels/scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

when running `python ./megatron/fused_kernels/setup.py install`?

Comment: It depends on the `-o` and `-c` compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

The .o file is included in the .exe/.out file if you don't compile the .cpp file with the -c compiler flag. But if you use the -c compiler flag, it is stored in the same directory as the .cpp file.

Comment: Thank you for r your reply, but why can't I find it in the same directory as the .cpp file? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with the -o compiler flag?

Comment: I used "python ./megatron/fused_kernels/setup.py install" to do the build which includes compiling. How to compile with the -o compiler flag? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have the g++ compiler installed? If yes, you can manually compile with the command: "g++ -c fullPathToYourFile/fileName.cpp" without quotes in your console.

Comment: Thank you for your message. But how to install the correct version of g++ for Cuda 10 on the Container-Optimized OS of Linux? Thanks a lot.